# SWT browser in Eclipse unable to access localStorage

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, microsoft-edge

I am developing a plugin for Eclipse using a React App. The app creates a SWT Browser and tries to access localStorage but fails to access the storage due to the following error :

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

The Browser is created using new Browser(parent,SWT.EDGE). Any hints on what could be wrong. This is on Windows.